# What is _IO_stdin_used

Tags: c++, assembly, printf, x86-64, reverse-engineering

Can someone explain me what `_IO_stdin_used` is in the following line:

```
114a:   48 8d 3d b3 0e 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xeb3]        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
```

Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: It's an internal implementation detail of some library you are using (I'd guess the C++ standard library). You shouldn't need to care, unless you are debugging that library; in the latter case you'd need to consult its source code.

Comment: It’s an internal detail of the standard library implementation that comes with your compiler.

Comment: Note that the LEA is actually loading an address 4 bytes after that; `_IO_stdin_used` is just the most recent global symbol in your executable.  (Perhaps in a stripped binary?)  I'd guess the symbol exists to let libc startup code decide whether to init stdio buffers or not, but whatever it is, it's totally irrelevant to this instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes 's comment ([What is _IO_stdin_used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595580/what-is-io-stdin-used#comment131672388_74595580) ), some tools can help make sense of this. Starting with `burt.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void) {
  puts("hello!");
}
```

built like so: `LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Map=burt.map make burt`

We will look at the map file in a moment, first inspect the executable:

```
$ objdump -xsd -M intel burt
...
0000000000002000 g     O .rodata        0000000000000004              _IO_stdin_used
...
Contents of section .rodata:
 2000 01000200 68656c6c 6f2100             ....hello!.
...
    1148:       48 8d 05 b5 0e 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0xeb5]        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    114f:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    1152:       e8 d9 fe ff ff          call   1030 <puts@plt>
...
```

Note, the string's location (2004h) does not have an entry in the symbol table (where the 2000h entry `_IO_stdin_used` occurs). So, objdump's disassembly comments mention it relative to another symbol it knows about.

But why does it know about `_IO_stdin_used`, or, why does is that symbol included and why does it have a name? `burt.map` shows it came from `Scrt1.o`:

```
...
.rodata         0x0000000000002000        0xb
 *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
 .rodata.cst4   0x0000000000002000        0x4 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o
 .rodata        0x0000000000002004        0x7 /tmp/ccYG1XvK.o
...
```

On my computer, `Scrt1.o` belongs to glibc, and the symbol can be traced back here: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/init.c;h=c2f978f3da565590bcab355fefa3d81cf211cb36;hb=63fb8f9aa9d19f85599afe4b849b567aefd70a36.

To show that this is displayed in the `objdump` disassembly because there is no name for the address, we can give our string a name to add it to the symbol table, so that `objdump` will show it instead. To do this let's modify `burt.c` like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char greeting[] = "hello!";
void main (void) {
  puts(greeting);
}
```

Build, then inspect:

```
...
0000000000002004 g     O .rodata        0000000000000007              greeting
...
0000000000002000 g     O .rodata        0000000000000004              _IO_stdin_used
...
Contents of section .rodata:                                                                     
 2000 01000200 68656c6c 6f2100             ....hello!.
...
    113d:       48 8d 05 c0 0e 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0xec0]        # 2004 <greeting>
    1144:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    1147:       e8 e4 fe ff ff          call   1030 <puts@plt>
```

The offset relative to `rip` has changed a little bit, because the `.text` and `.rodata` sections are now a little bit further apart, although the `.rodata` contents remain the same, because the source modification was chosen to avoid modifying `.rodata` -- if `greetings` were not `const`, it would be located in `.data` instead. The map file below now shows `burt.c`'s temporary object files's contribution to `.rodata` defining the `greeting` symbol, as compared to the previous map file where the same data had no name:

```
.rodata         0x0000000000002000        0xb                                                    
 *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)                                                          
 .rodata.cst4   0x0000000000002000        0x4 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.1/../../../..
/lib/Scrt1.o
                0x0000000000002000                _IO_stdin_used
 .rodata        0x0000000000002004        0x7 /tmp/ccDnWXjG.o
                0x0000000000002004                greeting
```